# a proxy type with the name account has been defined by another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

- We have 2 orgs running in our on-premise crm 2011 system.
- We have generated early bound classes for both orgs.
- One of our plugins is throwing the "a proxy type with the name account has been defined by another assembly" error when deactivating an account.
- That plugin only references one of the early bound dll's.

How do I get the CRM system to respect the namespace of these references.
I've tried the few items that show up from Google and none are working.

Since you can reproduce this with 2 vanilla orgs I would imaging there is something OUTSIDE the code layer we can do without having to go back and refactor a bunch of code for the 2 orgs.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Is the plugin registered in the sandbox?  Are you sure that the namespace is different for both generated files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this normally means that there is one or more assemblies with the same method name or property to fix this use the fully qualified name of the assembly.. for example in the using System.IO for example if you had a method named the same way in your Class code that conflicts with System.IO.... you would write your fix like 
thisObject.System.IO.Path(   ---- ) = somthing for example.. does this make sense..?

Comment: thx for the comment. I believe this is an issue specific to CRM 2011 doing some type of reflection loading and caching rather then an ambiguous reference.

Comment: Does CRM use something in the affect of Loading a particular assembly.. sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: no worries, I don't think anyone really understands what CRM is doing :D. Yes, from what I've read the CRM does some type of type caching across all orgs. Which would cause an obvious issue since they ALL have te same built-in types.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is actually with WCF attempting to deserialize the server response and not being able to identify the correct type. The best method to sort this issue is to pass in the current assembly using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() to the ProxyTypesBehavior() while creating the proxy like so.

```
using (serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(config.OrganizationUri,
                config.HomeRealmUri,
                config.Credentials,
                config.DeviceCredentials))
        {
            // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
            serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
        }
```

Comment: If you need to do this with an OrgnizationService (Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService) instance (like you would if you're using CrmConnection), then you need to create a wrapper class around the OrganizationService so you can access the ToOrganizationServiceProxy method and remove the default behavior then add the new one from above.

Answer (score 4):

You may run into this issue when referencing different assemblies containing proxy-classes, i.e. one assembly wrapping the server SDK (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk) and another assembly wrapping the client SDK (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client).
In such a scenario it seems to be required to tell the OrganizationServiceProxy which assembly should be used to resolve the proxy classes.

This should help:

```
var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

var proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(discoveryUrl), null, credentials, null);
proxy.EnableProxyTypes(typeof(CrmServiceContext).Assembly);

var context = CrmServiceContext(proxy);
```

The important thing is to call EnableProxyTypes by passing the correct assembly. I saw another [solution using CrmConnection](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmitchmilam/archive/2013/07/17/error-proxy-type-with-the-name-account-has-been-defined-by-another-assembly) but CrmConnection is only available in the client SDK, which means that you can't instantiate a "server-OrganizationServiceProxy" this way. EnableProxyTypes(Assembly assembly) works for both sides.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
MH

Answer (score 1):

It maybe years since this question has been raised. However, I faced this problem recently and have been extremely worried about thousands of lines of code to be changed. However, I was lucky to find the following simple change to get myself out of hell:

Suppose there are two context objects you deal with:

1. an OrganizationServiceContext object: context1
2. a CrmSvcUtil Context object: context2

and a single OrganizationServiceProxy object: service

if in a single method, you make multiple CRUD operations using the same service object but with either of context objects as exemplified above, it is highly probable that this error be raised. However, by doing the following, you can prevent it to happen.

Every time you want to work with context1, you precede the context object with the service object as following:

```
service.EnableProxyTypes(typeof(OrganizationServiceContext).Assembly);
using (var context1 = new OrganizationServiceContext(_service)){
    // your classic code here
}
```

Also, every time you want to work with context2, you follow the same structure:

```
service.EnableProxyTypes(typeof(HiwebContext).Assembly);
using (var context = new XYZContext(this._service)){
    // your CrmSvcUtil  none-classic code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

adding the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() solve my problem, you also need to add `using System.Reflection;`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue also occurs on .Net6 when using OpenAPI and the new Dataverse Client (ServiceClient).
Only fix I've found is cloning the setted up ServiceClient with the Assembly reference:

```
ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataverseUrl")), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataverseClientId"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataverseSecret"), false, log);

ServiceClient service = serviceClient.Clone(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), log);
```